# Get element by id from existing jQuery object

Tags: jquery

Ok this has got to be a stupid simple one, but I just can't find the documentation

```
  <ul>
      <li class="foo" id="jack"  ></li>
      <li class="foo" id="jill"  ></li>
      <li class="foo" id="tom"   ></li>
      <li class="foo" id="dick"  ></li>
      <li class="foo" id="harry" ></li>
  </ul>
```

And the simple jQuery

```
 var listItems = $('li.foo');
```

now how do I get #jack from `listItems` ? I already know `.eq() .get() .find()` ect. but not one that will work in one move. Not based on index, not looking for a child or parent, but based on the id of existing elements selected. Anyone know this one?

Comment: @isbadawi Because `.find()` looks for elements that are descendents of the elements in the jQuery object that match the selector. Since the element he wants is already part of the jQuery object, that won't be the case.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Ya I got it, deleted my comment right as you posted. How embarrassing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you're dealing with an id there is no need to do a sub-query.  An ID is unique and can just be queried directly

```
$('#jack')
```

If you did want to do a sub-query though for a non-ID value then look to `filter`

```
$('ul li').filter('.foo')
```

Comment: I am specifically asking how to do a subquery.

Comment: @Fresheyeball for an ID though you never do a sub-query.  They're unique.

Comment: Not only are they unique, but it's an order of magnitude faster. http://jsperf.com/filter-vs-id-lookup

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) like so:

```
listItems.filter('#jack');
```